# Visual Studio error: No se puede iniciar el programa(Unable to start program)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Quisiera saber porqué al hacer correr el siguiente código sale una ventanita en la cual dice:

> no se puede iniciar el program

seguido de:

> no se puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Además da estos errores:

> 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe.  Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
>
> 'fprintf': unknown type field character '' in format specifier

El objetivo del programa:

1. Abrir y leer un archivo .txt
2. Ordenar la información en orden ascendente de acuerdo al número de avión.
3. Guardar los datos ordenados en un nuevo archivo.
4. Buscar los datos de acuerdo al tipo de avión.

Podrían ayudarme por favor, hay algún error en el código?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "conio.h"
#define n 7

using namespace std;

struct AEROFLOT
{
    char name[20];
    int number;
    char plane[10];
} *pm;

void Print(AEROFLOT*);
void WriteFile(AEROFLOT*, char*);
void Sort(AEROFLOT*);
void InputType(AEROFLOT*);

int main()
{
    const char *fname = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\aeroflot.txt";

    FILE* file = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        pm = new AEROFLOT[n];
        fread(pm, sizeof AEROFLOT, n, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "List of airplanes: ";
    Print(pm);
    Sort(pm);
    cout << "Sorted list: ";
    Print(pm);
    WriteFile(pm, "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\aeroflot1.txt");
    InputType(pm);
    delete [] pm;
    _getch();
}

void Print(AEROFLOT array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        cout << "Destination: " << array.name << endl;
        cout << "Number of airplane: " << array.number << endl;
        cout << "Type of airplane: " << array.plane << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------------------\n" << endl;
    }
}

void WriteFile(AEROFLOT* array, char* fname) 
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(fname, "wt");
    if (!file) cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fprintf(file, "%10s -- %5 -- %10s\n", array[i].name, array[i].number, array[i].plane);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void Sort(AEROFLOT* array)
{
    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        index = i;
        AEROFLOT tmp;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (array[index].number < array[j].number)
                index = j;
        }
        if (index != i)
        {
            tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[index];
            array[index] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

void InputType(AEROFLOT* array)
{
    char* type;
    cout << "\nEnter type of airplane: "; cin >> type; 
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (type == array[i].plane)
        {
            cout << "Destination: " << array[i].name;
            cout << "Number of airplane: " << array[i].number << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "There isn't an airplane of this type." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (file != NULL) {} else { std::cout << "File error" << std::endl; return 1; }`. Añade la parte `else` tras ese `if` que hay en el `main` tras abrir el fichero, a ver si tienes problemas intentando abrir el fichero.

Comment: Por otro lado, la cadena `fname` debe ser de tipo `const char* fname`. Los literales de cadena `"..."` son constantes (todas las constantes y los literales de cadena se mapean en una zona de memoria de solo lectura al ejecutar).

Comment: He añadido todo esto, pero sigue saliendo la misma ventana de error.

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con mis cambios, para ver exáctamente qué has añadido en el código.

Comment: Más errores, quita `conio.h`, no es estándar C++. Por otro lado, las librerías del sistema deben ir entre ángulos `<iostream>`, `<fstream>`. "stdafx.h" no se exáctamente si es una librería del sistema o un fichero local (sé que es una cabecera precompilada de visual studio para agilizar compilación). Quita "stdafx.h" de la lista de `includes`. Y mira a ver, porque no tengo claro si te está dando errores al compilar, o al ejecutar (nunca he trabajado con VisualStudio).

Answer (score 1):

> Quisiera saber porqué al hacer correr el siguiente código sale una ventanita en la cual dice:
>
> > no se puede iniciar el program
>
> seguido de:
>
> > no se puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Ese error puede darse porque en la configuración de proyecto de VS la ruta de generación del ejecutable y la ruta de ejecución del mismo no coinciden.

Si abres el [panel de propiedades de tu proyecto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx):
[image]

Podrás ver un panel con varias opciones cuyo título será `tu proyecto Property Pages`.
[image]

Las opciones que deberás revisar son:

- Configuration Properties.

  - General.

    1. **Output Directory**: ruta se copiará el archivo ejecutable que tu aplicación genera.
  - Debugging.

    2. **Command**: orden se le dará al sistema operativo para ejecutar el programa.
    3. **Working Directory**: ruta de ejecución de tu programa, esto es: la ruta desde la que el programa verá los archivos y carpetas.

Si no has tocado las opciones resaltadas estas deberían tener los valores por defecto `$(OutDir)`, `$(TargetPath)` y `$(ProjectDir)` respectivamente y todo debería funcionar con normalidad.

Si has tocado alguna de las opciones, éstas se verán en negrita y si las rutas son incorrectas VS no pueda encontrar el archivo ejecutable, mostrando errores parecidos a los que describes.

Podría suceder que no hubieses tocado estas opciones pero que aún así estén mal configuradas... ¿has descargado el proyecto por internet o lo has generado con alguna herramienta como Make?

---

> Además da estos errores:
>
> > 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
> >
> > 'fprintf': unknown type field character '' in format specifier

Estos errores son bastante auto-explicativos.

El primer error indica que la función `fopen` se considera poco segura y aconseja usar `fopen_s` en su lugar. `fopen` pertenece a las librerías de C adaptadas a C++ (en este caso forma parte de la cabecera `<cstdio>`).

Generalmente muchas de las funciones de librerías C se consideran inseguras por no poder ser usadas en [entornos concurrentes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrencia_(inform%C3%A1tica)), porque no hacen comprobaciones de [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) o punteros inválidos/nulos o por todos esos motivos a la vez; para intentar resolver estos problemas se ofrecen funciones seguras que normalmente tienen el sufijo `_s`.

El segundo error indica que has añadido una marca de formato desconocida en la función `fprintf`, las marcas de formato más habituales puedes verlas [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Formateadores).

Entre las marcas de formato permitidas no está la `%5` que estás usando aquí:

```
fprintf(file, "%10s -- %5 -- %10s\n", array[i].name, array[i].number, array[i].plane);
```

Lo que seguramente genera el error.

Answer (score 0):

Por el error de "no se puede encontrar el archivo especificado"
estás seguro de que es correcto el path y tenés los permisos necesarios ?

Por este warning "'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS."

Agregá como primera linea de código esto:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE 
#endif
```

o usá fopen_s

Para "'fprintf': unknown type field character '' in format specifier"

fijate que el 2do parámetro del fprint dice %5 te falta el d => %5d